# Why is my GitHub deployment failing?

Tags: git, azure

I am new to Azure and setup a simple static web app attached to GitHub repository and in the Deployment Options the logs show the following:

```
Done! Find your new .html resume at D:\home\site\repository/index.html
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Error: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
Copying file: 'index.html'
Failed exitCode=1, command="kudusync" -v 50 -f "D:\home\site\repository" -t "D:\home\site\wwwroot" -n "D:\home\site\deployments\21e32b88c232158b22c2ed4d6e60e9e7f5faeae0\manifest" -p "D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\63.60608.2880\bin\Scripts\firstDeploymentManifest" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Could Not Find D:\home\site\repository\web.config\r\nError: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\63.60608.2880\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd deploy.cmd
```

Here are the contents from Azure:
    D:\home\site\deployments\21e32b88c232158b22c2ed4d6e60e9e7f5faeae0
    Volume in drive D is Windows
     Volume Serial Number is F8BE-15BD

```
 Directory of D:\home\site\deployments\21e32b88c232158b22c2ed4d6e60e9e7f5faeae0

06/14/2017  11:39 PM    <DIR>          .
06/14/2017  11:39 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/14/2017  11:39 PM             3,212 log.log
06/14/2017  11:39 PM               650 status.xml
           2 File(s)          3,862 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  53,650,538,496 bytes free

D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\63.60608.2880\bin\Scripts
Volume in drive D is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is F8BE-15BD

 Directory of D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\63.60608.2880\bin\Scripts

06/12/2017  03:03 PM    <DIR>          .
06/12/2017  03:03 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/12/2017  03:03 PM            39,936 CommandLine.dll
06/12/2017  03:03 PM            66,419 deployedJob.html.template
06/12/2017  03:03 PM               174 deploy_webjobs.cmd
06/12/2017  03:03 PM            71,313 dnvm.ps1
06/12/2017  03:03 PM                17 firstDeploymentManifest
06/12/2017  03:03 PM               486 go.web.config.template
06/12/2017  03:03 PM             2,587 iisnode.config.template
06/12/2017  03:03 PM            16,384 KuduHandles.exe
06/12/2017  03:03 PM                49 kudusync
06/12/2017  03:03 PM                66 kudusync.cmd
06/12/2017  03:03 PM            24,064 KuduSync.NET.exe
06/12/2017  03:03 PM               285 KuduSync.NET.exe.config
06/12/2017  03:03 PM         4,658,392 NuGet.exe
06/12/2017  03:03 PM             1,295 runDnxWebJob.cmd
06/12/2017  03:03 PM               690 selectLatestVersion.ps1
06/12/2017  03:03 PM            16,624 selectNodeVersion.js
06/12/2017  03:03 PM             2,565 select_python_version.py
06/12/2017  03:03 PM            33,707 semver.js
06/12/2017  03:03 PM                 5 starter.cmd
06/12/2017  03:03 PM                30 starter.sh
06/12/2017  03:03 PM            23,040 System.IO.Abstractions.dll
              21 File(s)      4,958,128 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   5,106,651,136 bytes free
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

It's literally telling you what's wrong.

A file you're trying to read/write has a fully-qualified path (e.g. C:...) that is > 260 characters.

Comment: That I understand trying to figure out which github file it is. Since this site is being deployed from the repository. The clue must be the manifest file which is being generated from deployment.cmd

Comment: @CodeVista what are the contents of the following files: "D:\home\site\deployments\21e32b88c232158b22c2ed4d6e60e9e7f5faeae0\manifest" and "D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\63.60608.2880\bin\Scripts\firstDeploymentManifest"? Update your question to include these.

Comment: Thanks for you help Clint